# How to simply extract many repetitive rows from dataframe

Tags: r

How do I easily generate this sequence?

```
c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9,1,10,
   2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2,7,2,8,2,9,2,10)
```

Is there any simple way to write this?

Comment: Do you want it to continue logically, i.e., `3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, ...` or are you happy with the length you have? The `df %>% slice` seems unrelated to your question (especially since you don't provide `df`). I think your question would be clearer if it was just "how do I generate this sequence?"

Comment: Thanks for feedback, i edited the question.

Comment: I want it to continue logically yes, at least for the length of my data frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a partially-`dplyr` solution. (Of course it would be trivial to use a replacement for `filter()` and not use the pipes...) `expand.grid` normally works well for this, but in this case it's a little more complicated than CPak's use of `combn` because we have to switch the column order:

```
expand.grid(1:10, 1:10) %>% rev %>% filter(Var2 < Var1) %>% t %>% as.vector
 [1]  1  2  1  3  1  4  1  5  1  6  1  7  1  8  1  9  1 10  2  3  2  4  2  5  2  6  2
[28]  7  2  8  2  9  2 10  3  4  3  5  3  6  3  7  3  8  3  9  3 10  4  5  4  6  4  7
[55]  4  8  4  9  4 10  5  6  5  7  5  8  5  9  5 10  6  7  6  8  6  9  6 10  7  8  7
[82]  9  7 10  8  9  8 10  9 10
```

---

Adding a `base` method:

```
n = 10
unlist(lapply(1:(n - 1), FUN = function(x) as.vector(rbind(x, (x + 1):n))))
```

For large n, I would expect this to be quite a bit faster as it doesn't use data frames at all and doesn't generate unneeded combinations and then filter them out.

Comment: Thank you! This was a quick and simple solution, worked perfectly!

Comment: Could you elaborate what the %>% t %>% as.vector does? Converts it to a list, then to a vector?

Comment: `?t` is the transpose so that its in the order you want (R uses column major order by default). And then `as.vector` makes it a 1-dimensional instead of a matrix. Try without the `t` and see what it looks like (maybe with n = 3). Feel free to experiment - you'll understand much better than my explanation.

Answer (score 6):

I think you want something like

```
t(combn(1:10, 2))

      # [,1] [,2]
 # [1,]    1    2
 # [2,]    1    3
 # [3,]    1    4
 # [4,]    1    5
 # [5,]    1    6
 # [6,]    1    7
 # [7,]    1    8
 # [8,]    1    9
 # [9,]    1   10
# [10,]    2    3
# [11,]    2    4
# [12,]    2    5
# [13,]    2    6
# [14,]    2    7
# [15,]    2    8
# [16,]    2    9
# [17,]    2   10
# etc
```

As data frame

```
as.data.frame(t(combn(1:10, 2)))
```

Comment: I think what OP wants is `as.vector()` of that, not `as.data.frame()`. Nice answer!

Comment: Ah, I was a bit confused by the title. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `base R` way.

```
fun <- function(x, k) c(k, x)

n <- 10
res <- lapply(seq_len(n - 1), function(k) sapply((k + 1):n, fun, k))
unlist(lapply(res, c))
# [1]  1  2  1  3  1  4  1  5  1  6  1  7  1  8  1  9  1 10  2  3  2  4  2  5  2
#[26]  6  2  7  2  8  2  9  2 10  3  4  3  5  3  6  3  7  3  8  3  9  3 10  4  5
#[51]  4  6  4  7  4  8  4  9  4 10  5  6  5  7  5  8  5  9  5 10  6  7  6  8  6
#[76]  9  6 10  7  8  7  9  7 10  8  9  8 10  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little function using base R that allows you to control the starting and stopping values.

```
combos <- function(x, y) unlist(Map(rbind, as.list(1:x), lapply(2:(x+1), ":", y)))

combos(3, 10)
 [1]  1  2  1  3  1  4  1  5  1  6  1  7  1  8  1  9  1 10  2  3  2  4  2  5  2  6  2
[28]  7  2  8  2  9  2 10  3  4  3  5  3  6  3  7  3  8  3  9  3 10
combos(2, 5)
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 2 3 2 4 2 5
combos(3, 5)
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 2 3 2 4 2 5 3 4 3 5
```

Comment: Much simpler than mine, `identical`returns `TRUE`. You have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `result` is the final output. You may want to further subset the `result` vector or subset the `df2` for your needs. After seeing Gregor's answer, I think my original approach is too complicated and thus I updated the approach as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  complete(a, b) %>%
  filter(b > a)

result <- dt2 %>% 
  t() %>%
  as.vector()

result
 [1]  1  2  1  3  1  4  1  5  1  6  1  7  1  8  1  9  1 10  2  3  2  4  2  5  2  6  2
[28]  7  2  8  2  9  2 10  3  4  3  5  3  6  3  7  3  8  3  9  3 10  4  5  4  6  4  7
[55]  4  8  4  9  4 10  5  6  5  7  5  8  5  9  5 10  6  7  6  8  6  9  6 10  7  8  7
[82]  9  7 10  8  9  8 10  9 10
```

Because row is sorted based on column `a`, you can filter the column `a` based on the number you need. For example, if you only want the first number no bigger than 2. You can do the following for your `df2`

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  complete(a, b) %>%
  filter(b > a) %>%
  filter(a < 3)
```

Using `df2` for the same code to generate `result` as mentioned above, you will get the same desired output as your example.

Answer (score 0):

I used a for loop. If you want a long sequence, this will not be your best choice:

```
# Create vectors for desired sequence
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:2

# Initiate sequence vector
seq <- c()

# Loop to fill in sequence vector
for(elem in y){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
      toappend <- c(elem, x[i])
      seq <- c(seq, toappend)
    }
  }

> print(seq)
 [1]  1  1  1  2  1  3  1  4  1  5  1  6  1  7  1  8  1  9  1 10  2  1  2  2  2  3  2  4  2
[30]  5  2  6  2  7  2  8  2  9  2 10
```